# Invalid date value after parse

Tags: java

I am new to java. I have a Date that is stored in the variable, `pubDate = "2013-09-23"`

When I'm executing this

```
SimpleDateFormat pubSimpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
Date publishDate = pubSimpleDateFormat.parse(pubDate);
```

I'm getting wrong value : Wed Jan 23 00:09:00 GMT+05:30 2013

Please help me why it so. and help me to solve this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`M` is for Month in year while `m` is for Minute in hour

You should use `SimpleDateFormat pubSimpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");`

```
String pubDate = "2013-09-23";
SimpleDateFormat pubSimpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date publishDate = pubSimpleDateFormat.parse(pubDate);
System.out.println(publishDate);
```

Output :

> Mon Sep 23 00:00:00 GMT 2013

Read the section [Date and Time Patterns](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: Great...Within in seconds.Good job..:)

Comment: @user2925107 it is always nice to accept and upvote the answer that helped you much.